# Convert from timezone datetime to short date C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, timezone-offset

I have datetime data that looks like this: `2018-06-29T22:10:33Z`.

I need it in Short date format - `06/29/2018` i.e., without the time part.

I have tried the following in C#:

```
ConvertToDateTime(dateString);
DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Errors with both.

I'm resorting to `dateString.substring(0,10)` to get the 1st 10 characters and convert that to date.

Is there a better method?

Comment: "22:1033" is a very odd format. Does it really not have a second colon between the minutes and the seconds? And do you know whether it's *always* in UTC, or whether sometimes there might be a UTC offset there instead of Z?

Comment: My bad. There is in fact a second colon. This is ALWAYS the timestamp I'm encountering in the data.

Comment: What's the error? Because it's working for me the `Parse` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTime.TryParse method. ie:

```
string s = "2018-06-29T22:10:33Z";
DateTime t;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out t))
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToShortDateString());
}
```

To get UTC date:

```
string s = "2018-06-29T22:10:33Z";

DateTime t;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out t))
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToUniversalTime().ToShortDateString());
}
```

Comment: If `DateTime.Parse` doesn't work, neither will `DateTime.TryParse`

Comment: @AstroRP, I didn't say otherwise, TryParse has advantage in error handling.

Comment: @AstroRP: That's right. I did try TryParse as well. The issue seems to be that the source date time might be non-standard as I don't see it in MSDN documentation either.

Comment: @GVashist, it is standard, you only had a typo in not having a colon before the seconds part.

Comment: @GVashist, did you mean to get the UTC date? I am adding code for that.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: Thank you. I did notice that and I see that's what my data looks like as well since its a string value. Must be a mistake upstream. That being said, how would I convert a string that looks like that 2018-06-29T22:10:33Z to short date string?

Comment: @GVashist, I already gave code to convert it to a short date string.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Now to take care of the root cause upstream with the missing colon.

Comment: @GVashist if you can't fix the upstream, you could also use the `ParseExact` method and provide a custom format string. [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx); [Custom Datetime string formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the date format appears to be not well formatted. The format you should be receiving should like "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK" (i.e. "2018-06-29T22:10:05.1440844Z").

Assuming there was a typo in the sample date provided, here are a couple of samples to convert the date time string (in UTC format) to a DateTime:

```
var dateString = "2018-06-29T22:10:05.1440844Z";

var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date = datetime.Date;
```

or

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date = datetime.Date;
```

You have to take into consideration that you are getting a UTC date and timezone conversions must be taken into consideration. Also, when just taking the date part, the time part is set to "12:00:00 AM".